# Failed to build gem native extension ( em-irc )

Tags: ruby, rubygems, require, mkmf

Trying to install em-irc, got that:

```
/usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
from /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from extconf.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running as root: `sudo gem install em-irc`